# What are the peculiarities of a school or company of the prophets לַהֲקַ֚ת הַנְּבִיאִים֙ (1 Samuel 19:20)?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mesorah-tradition, nevua-prophecy, samuel-shmuel-book-of, machlokes

What are the peculiarities of a school or company of the prophets לַהֲקַ֚ת הַנְּבִיאִים֙ (I Samuel 19:20)?

What did one learn in a school of the prophets?
How did one become a student in a school of the prophets?
What was a typical school day in such a company?

What other peculiarities are there in such a company of the prophets, as according to the sages and other authorities, apart from the fact that such no longer exists?

Comment: How to not get knocked on your back? how to manage nausea?

Comment: @הראל If you can source it legitimately, yes

Comment: Source my questions legitimately?

Answer (score 3):

The Ramchal provides a nice summary of how these schools for prophecy worked in [Part Three of Derech Hashem](https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_HaShem%2C_Part_Three%2C_On_the_Prophetic_Experience.2?lang=bi):

"The teaching to those learning: Indeed, the prophecy students would study given topics [about] what would bring down the influence of the Most High; how one would nullify any barriers from the material body and bring about the revelation of His light, may He be blessed and the cleaving to Him; and more generally, the mention of holy names, praises that would be joined with names in the ways of combination, as we wrote earlier."

Comment: I read your source, as you linked it above, but it neither references לַהֲקַ֚ת הַנְּבִיאִים֙ nor I Samuel 19.

Comment: @ninamag but it does refer to בני הנביאים, who are the Kings-era equivalents of להקת הנביאים from the time of Shmuel.

Comment: From whom did the Ramchal source his comments?